# How to use kubernetes secret with "kubectrl run"

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am deploying a kubernetes cluster using ansible.

Now I want to create the databases inside the cluster also using ansible.

Since the database server is only reachable inside the cluster, I figured, I start a pod inside the kluster using `kubectrl run` which in turn runs a script to create the database. Like this:

```
- name: Run database create script
  shell: kubectl run db-create --rm -i --image mysql-client -- sh < mysql_create_script.sh
```

That works!

But now I want to use secrets inside the script, for example the mysql root password.
I could extract the secret from kubernetes like this:

```
- name: Get secret
  shell: "kubectl get secret mysql-root-user -ojson"
  register: secret_output

... (extract password from output json) ...
```

But it would be much nicer, if the secret would be available inside the pod I am creating for my database creation script.

I can set envrionment variables via `--env VAR=VAL`, but can I also set envrionment variables from secrets somehow when using `kubectrl run`?

Comment: You can make secrets available inside the pod by using `secretKeyRef` (see [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data) ) if that what you need

Comment: That is what I need. But how can use a `secretKeyRef` in combination with `kubectrl run`?

Comment: Ansible has a native [`k8s`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html#ansible-collections-community-kubernetes-k8s-module) module; you might use that to create a Job, which can do things like set environment variables from Secret values.

Comment: In addition to David's great suggestion, there's also [`connection: kubectl`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/connection/kubectl.html) where you can use your normal `environment: {MYSQL_PASSWORD: "{{whatever}}"}` syntax in the ansible `command:` to run inside the existing mysql container (it requires a working python in the container, so you may have to try `raw:` and hope it recognizes `environment:`)